# How do I perform a calculation on a column when using a DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I need to calculate sum of a column and display it in `total.Text`. How can I achieve this? This column have unlimited data that can always change. I'm using VS2010. I m new to C#.

Example:

```
_____________________
| last_retail_price |
---------------------
|      500          |
|      200          |
|      5.60         |
---------------------
total.Text = 705.6  \\ The sum of column which I need
```

My code:

```
private void add_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable tl = new DataTable();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select last_ret_prc from pur_temp", con);
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(tl);

    object sum_obj;
    sum_obj = tl.Compute("sum(last_ret_prc)");
    total.Text = sum_obj.ToString();
    con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, your code is never going to work:

- Column name is last_retail_price, but you've used last_ret_prc in the code.
- con.close should be con.Close().
- DataTable.Compute takes two arguments "expression" and "filter".  You still need to provide the second argument, even if it is null.

I've cleaned up the code and tested it locally and it works fine:

```
SqlConnection con =
    new SqlConnection(
        @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\fuda\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable tl = new DataTable();
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select last_retail_price from pur_temp", con);
con.Open();
da.Fill(tl);

object sum_obj = tl.Compute("sum(last_retail_price)", null);
total.Text = sum_obj.ToString();
con.Close();
```

Alternatively, if your only wish is to display the total, you would probably be best doing this in one SqlCommand:

```
con.Open();
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(last_retail_price) FROM pur_temp", con);
var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
total.Text = result.ToString();
con.Close();
```

Comment: here its giving me error in below line
object sum_obj = tl.Compute("sum(last_retail_price)", null);
\\Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.
same error in all above codings even mine too....

Comment: last_retail_price in your database needs to be a numeric type - decimal(18,2).  I suspect you're currently storing a string (char/nchar/varchar/nvarchar)?

The error suggests that you're attempting to Sum a string - Sum(500, 200, 5.60) is valid where Sum("500", "200", "5.60") is not.

Comment: i have another idea that you can help me some think like : int a = column1 & row 1 , int 2 = column1 & row 2 , int 3 = column1 & row 3 and so on at least 20 i mean same column but different rows then sum all int like total.text = 1+2+3+4+5.....20 is it possible ??

Comment: Here i m using VarChar(Max) for last_ret_prc in datable that is wrong. thank alot both of you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var con = new SqlConnection(/*your connection string*/);
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"Select Sum(last_ret_prc) FROM pur_temp GROUP BY last_ret_prc";
string sum_obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

total.Text = sum_obj;

con.Dispose();
```

Now the SQL query is just returning one value. The sum of the `last_ret_prc`.
The method `ExecuteScaler()` returns the first value from the first column in the first row.